# Find duration by hour

Tags: r, time, datatable, duration, lubridate

I have a following dataframe (length is in seconds):

```
dates<-data.frame(start=as.POSIXct(c("2010-04-03 03:02:38 UTC","2010-04-03 06:03:14 UTC","2010-04-20 03:05:52 UTC","2010-04-20 03:17:42 UTC","2010-04-21 03:09:38 UTC","2010-04-21 07:10:14 UTC","2010-04-21 08:12:52 UTC","2010-04-23 03:13:42 UTC","2010-04-23 03:25:42 UTC","2010-04-23 03:36:38 UTC","2010-04-23 08:58:14 UTC","2010-04-24 03:21:52 UTC","2010-04-24 03:22:42 UTC","2010-04-24 07:24:19 UTC","2010-04-24 07:55:19 UTC")),length=c(3600,300,900,3600,300,900,3600,300,900,3600,300,900,3600,300,3600))

> dates
                 start length
1  2010-04-03 03:02:38   3600
2  2010-04-03 06:03:14    300
3  2010-04-20 03:05:52    900
4  2010-04-20 03:17:42   3600
5  2010-04-21 03:09:38    300
6  2010-04-21 07:10:14    900
7  2010-04-21 08:12:52   3600
8  2010-04-23 03:13:42    300
9  2010-04-23 03:25:42    900
10 2010-04-23 03:36:38   3600
11 2010-04-23 08:58:14    300
12 2010-04-24 03:21:52    900
13 2010-04-24 03:22:42   3600
14 2010-04-24 07:24:19    300
15 2010-04-24 07:55:19   3600
```

I want to calculate the total duration by hour, e.g. from 00:00:00 to 01:00:00, from 01:00:00 to 02:00:00 and so on. But sometimes the start is at 07:55:19 and the duration is 3600 (like in the last row) and I need to split it into 2 and count 281 sec for 07:00:00 to 08:00:00 period, and 3319 sec for 08:00:00 to 09:00:00 period.

I would find the total duration for 03:00:00-04:00:00 period like:

```
library(lubridate)

dates$endTime<-dates$start+dates$length
dates$newTime<-format(dates$start, format="%H:%M:%S")
dates$endTime<-format(dates$endTime, format="%H:%M:%S")
dates$dur3<-ifelse(hms(dates$endTime)<hms("04:00:00"), seconds(hms(dates$endTime)-hms(dates$newTime)), seconds(hms("04:00:00")-hms(dates$newTime)))

sum(dates[dates$dur3>0,"dur3"])
12920
```

I was thinking to just calculate the duration within each of the 24 periods for each row, and then just sum those, but what would be a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: How do you compute for example 04:00:00-05:00:00?

Comment: But how do you compute it still?

Comment: But it's calculated from rows 1,4,10 and 13: 158+1062+2198+1342=4760

Comment: why 882 instead of 772? also why 1342 instead of 1362?

Comment: Sorry, I think I did it wrong again. So in row #4 there is 17M:42S which whould be counted into  04:00:00-05:00:00, which is 1062 seconds, right?

Comment: I am just adding in R.. I guess. I am subtracting 3600-what is in 3

Comment: The end time for row # 4 is 04:17:42, so the duration for that hour should be library(lubridate) seconds(hms("04:17:42")-hms("04:00:00")) which is 1062S

Comment: Yes that one is 1062. But I do not understand why you have 1342 instead of 1362

Comment: What do you do with the dates$length column?

Comment: I will post my answer and see whether it suits you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> a=dates$start
> b=difftime(a+hours(1)-second(a)-minutes(minute(a)),a,units="secs")
> d=c(pmin(b,dates$length),replace(e<-dates$length-b,e<0,0))
> tapply(d,c(hour(a),hour(a)+1),sum)
    3     4     6     7     8     9 
12920  4780   300  1481  6253   966
```

Comment: If some of the lengths were 7200 or 10800 how would you adjust your code?

Comment: What is the meaning of lengths?? I just used it. How is it to be used?

Comment: length is duration, so if the start is 03:02:38 and the length is 3600 seconds, than the end is 04:02:38. It's just telling you the duration of the time interval, so that you can calculate the end of that time interval

Comment: Is that the reason when the length was less than 3600 you took that? I now see. So you want the length to be 7200 yet duration to remain 1 hour or 2 hours now?

Comment: yes, change any of the lengths to 7200 or 10800 and calculate the total for each hour as before.

Comment: I am abit confused. Would you mind asking that as a separate question and giving an example with the expected results? In that case I might understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on the question, even though I'm not entirely certain of the task: First, I calculate the overlap into the next hours

```
dates$rest <- 3600 - as.numeric(format(dates$start, "%M"))*60 - as.numeric(format(dates$start, "%S"))
dates$excess <- dates$length - dates$rest
```

Next, we loop over those lengths extending into the next hour, bearing in mind that this only works if the lengths are limited by 3600. as in the example. If not, the loop needs to be extended a bit.

```
for(row in which(dates$excess > 0)){
  row_to_copy <- dates[row, ]
  dates[row, "length"] <- dates[row, "length"] - row_to_copy$excess
  row_to_copy$start <- row_to_copy$start + 3600
  row_to_copy$length <- row_to_copy$excess
  dates <-rbind(dates, row_to_copy)
}
```

With the finished data set, we now define the column by which to group the hours. Note that we could also group by "Date - Hour" if we wish.

```
dates$hours <- format(dates$start, "%H")
res_df <-
  dates %>% 
  group_by(hours) %>%
  summarize(length_total = sum(length))
```

With the result

```
> res_df
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  hours length_total
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 03           13240
2 04            4460
3 06             300
4 07            1519
5 08            6347
6 09             834
```

Comment: I believe there is a mistake in the first line of your code, it should be: dates$rest <- 3600 - as.numeric(format(dates$start, "%M"))*60 - as.numeric(format(dates$start, "%S")) OR dates$rest <- 3600 - (as.numeric(format(dates$start, "%M"))*60 + as.numeric(format(dates$start, "%S")))

Comment: Then the output is exactly the same as in the other answer.